# How to count amount of data for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this table:

```
   ID       Name    01  02  03  04  05  06  07

0000068 Name1                       V   VX  

0000069 Name2       V   VX  VX      V       V

0000070 Name3           V   V   V   V   V   V
```

This is an table for absence check and I want to count the amount of data from each row from column 01 to 07, so I expect the first row will give result of 2, second row 5, and third row 6. And if possible I want that result to be added as a new column. Is there a way to work this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of columns is static, you can use a simple `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT *,
 CASE WHEN [01] = '' OR [01] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
 CASE WHEN [02] = '' OR [02] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
 CASE WHEN [03] = '' OR [03] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
 CASE WHEN [04] = '' OR [04] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
 CASE WHEN [05] = '' OR [05] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
 CASE WHEN [06] = '' OR [06] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
 CASE WHEN [07] = '' OR [07] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [cnt]
FROM Table1;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a3eee/1).

Comment: no NULL value so i removed the OR and it worked perfectly. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it's always `V` or `VX` you could replace the `VX` with `V`, concatenate 
them together and take the `LEN()`:

```
SELECT *, LEN(REPLACE([01]+[02]+[03]+[04]+[05]+[06]+[07],'X','')) AS New_Ct
FROM YourTable
```

If the blanks are actually `NULL` you'd have to wrap them in `ISNULL()`:

```
SELECT *, LEN(REPLACE(ISNULL([01],'')+ISNULL([02],'')+ISNULL([03],'')+ISNULL([04],'')+ISNULL([05],'')+ISNULL([06],'')+ISNULL([07],''),'X','')) AS New_Ct
FROM Table1
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4cb5/2/0)

Comment: it counts the length of characters huh? not what i was looking for as i only need the v or vx or x to be counted as 1, but another knowledge gained. thanks :)

Comment: @user3282706  The length of a single character string is 1, so this is indeed what you're after.  The only missing bit in your question was that X can be by itself, but that would just require changing the `,'X','')` portion to `,'VX','X')`  Just another way to skin the cat.

Comment: @GoatCO okay got it. but still doesn't work tho i tested: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7bbe/2/0

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 01+02+03+04+05+06+07 AS total_number FROM table_name;

Comment: I tested in sqlite, it worked if the value of each column is int, here if use 1 as the value.

Comment: Looks like OP has string values.

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood it. I thought "v", "vx" is the symbol to represent the value, not the real value.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
SELECT  ID,Name,
(Case When[01] IS Null or [01] = '' then 0 else 1 end) +
(Case When[02] IS Null or [02] = '' then 0 else 1 end) +
(Case When[03] IS Null or [03] = '' then 0 else 1 end) +
(Case When[04] IS Null or [04] = '' then 0 else 1 end) +
(Case When[05] IS Null or [05] = '' then 0 else 1 end) +
(Case When[06] IS Null or [06] = '' then 0 else 1 end) +
(Case When[07] IS Null or [07] = '' then 0 else 1 end) AS Total
FROM table1;
```

## [FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d751/7)